# Proof of the convolution property of Fourier Series in continuous time

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, fourier-series, proof

I am facing problem in understanding the proof of Convolution property of Fourier Series (FS) in continuous time CT;
that is:  $$\mathrm{FS} \big\{x_1(t)\star x_2(t)\big\}=T\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n d_ne^{j \Omega_0 n t}$$ where $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are periodic with $T$, and $c_n$ and $d_n$ are the Fourier series coefficient of $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$.

Below I am showing the proof and my confusion,

- **PROOF:**
  \begin{align}
  x_1(t)\star x_2(t) &= \int_T x_1(\tau)x_2(t-\tau)d\tau\\
  \therefore \mathrm{FS}\big\{x_1(t)\star x_2(t)\big\}&=\int_T FS[x_1(\tau)] FS[x_2(t-\tau)]d\tau\\ &=\int_T \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{j \Omega_0 n \tau} \sum_{p=-\infty}^{\infty}d_p e^{j \Omega_0 p (t- \tau)} d\tau\\
  &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{p=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n d_p \int_T e^{j \Omega_0 (n-p) \tau} e^{j \Omega_0 p t} d\tau\\
  &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n d_n T e^{j \Omega_0 n t}
  \end{align}
- **CONFUSION:**
  Now I am confused  how we are getting
  $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n d_n T e^{j \Omega_0 n t}  \quad\text{from}
  \quad\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{p=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n d_p \int_T e^{j \Omega_0 (n-p) \tau} e^{j \Omega_0 p t} d\tau \quad ?$$

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Show that with $\Omega_0=2\pi/T$

$$\int_T e^{j\Omega_0(n-p)\tau} d\tau=\begin{cases}T,&\quad n=p\\0,&\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So the sum over $p$ reduces to a single element $Td_ne^{j\Omega_0 nt}$, and the result follows.